# How to copy all data from an empty dir volume to my local machine?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, cp, volumes

I have a container with an empty dir volume

```yaml
 - volumes:
   emptyDir: {}
   name: someName
```

I would like to copy all data to my machine using `kubectl cp`.

I do not know where the `someName` volume is located. How can I find out and how can I copy the data from the volume to my local machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check in your pod where the volume is mounted. Check in the container sections, for a mount with the name `someName`, e.g:

```
containers:
  volumeMounts:
  - name: someName
    mountPath: "/mnt/path"
```

So you know that the emptyDir is mounted at the given mountPath.

Afterwards you can copy the files via

```
kubectl cp my-namespace/my-pod:/mnt/path /tmp/local/path
```